# Does the 95 Toyota Camry have a single belt for alternator, ac, power steering and drive?

Tags: toyota, camry, belt, serpentine-belt

The auto shop has offered to replace my 95 Camry's AC belt and P/S belt. I replaced the 'serpentine' belt myself (it took about five minutes) and no matter what googling I do, I can't find evidence of any other belts; this one seems to be in charge of it all. Are there any more belts (besides the timing belt) that I can replace myself?

Answer (score 1):

I should have watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xk0rUVLc3UQ) more closely. It does have a separate power steering belt located behind and below the drive belt.